# Polymer - dynamically register a property

Tags: polymer-1.0

Is there a way to register a property in a component after the component was already created?

Basically, I want to have the web component make a server request to find which properties to register, then register the properties once it gets a response.

For example:

Externally the component might be used as such:

```
<powco-interface name="form" data="{{data}}"></powco-interface>
```

but powco-interface doesn't know that it should register the data property with "notify: true" until after a server call.  So powco-interface makes the server call then on response registers the data property with "notify: true".

Note: powco-interface would get the value of the data property from a dynamically generated subcomponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your response (*this* is the polymer element context)

```
this.properties["data"] = {
    type: Object,
    value: newData,
    notify: true
}
```

But this is not very useful in my opinion, because there is no point of binding the property beforehand, just define the property like you normally do but do not assign value, Polymer won't fire notify.

Comment: also for your case I would strongly recommend using Polymer utility function `debounce()`